# Open sets of linear functions with respect to a metric

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, general-topology, sequence-of-function

> Let L be the set of all linear functions on $[0,1]$,
>   $f \in L \Leftrightarrow \exists a,b \in \mathbb{R} \forall x \in [0,1] f(x)=ax+b$
>
> Let $p(f,g) = sup_{x \in [0,1]}|f(x)-g(x)|$. Recall that $C[0,1]$ is the space of all real-valued continuous functions on interval $[0,1]$ with metric p.
>
> 1- I need to proof that L is not open in $C([0,1],p)$
>
> 2- I have to prove that if $f_n ∈ L$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and there exists a continuous function f such that for all $x \in [0, 1]$ we have $f_n(x) \rightarrow f(x)$ then f is linear and $ρ(f_n, f) \rightarrow 0$
>
> 3- Finally, prove that L is closed  in $(C[0, 1], ρ)$, i.e., that if $f_n \in L$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and there exists a continuous function f such that $ρ(f_n, f) \rightarrow 0$, then f is linear

In the first one I think i need to proof that for every $\epsilon > 0$ and every linear function $f(x) = ax+b$ there exists a continuous function g which is not linear and we have $p(f,g) < \epsilon$, but I'm not sure how to achieve that.

In the second one, coefficients $a_{n}$ and $b_n$ of every linear function $f_n$ are determined by two values of $f_n$, somewhere in [0, 1].

I guess the last one is a combination of the three others

Answer (score 1):

1- If $f$ is affine, let $f_n(x) = ax+b+ {1 \over n} x(1-x)$. Check that $\|f-f_n\| = {1 \over 4n}$.

2- If the $f_n$ are affine and $f_n(x) \to f(x)$, it is straightforward to check that
$f$ must be affine. If $a$ is affine it is straightforward to show that
$\|a|| = \max(|a(0)|, |a(1)|)$.

3- Define $A$ as follows: $(Af)(x) = f(x) -((f(1)-f(0))x+f(0))$. Check that $Af = 0$ **iff** $f$ is affine. Note that $\ker A$ is a closed set.

Comment: Could you elaborate a little further in the second point?

Comment: @schrader21: Suppose $f_n(x)=a_nx+b_n$. Since $f_n(0) \to f(0)$ and $f_n(1) \to f(1)$t is not hard to see that $a_n \to a, b_n \to b$ for some $a,b$. Now show that $f_n(x) = a_nx+b_n \to f(x)$ implies that $f(x) = ax+b$. If $f$ is affine it must be increasing, constant or decreasing, hence the norm is attained at either of the end points